# Spring Project in VSCode - Maven goal execution failed - unknown encoding name - utf8

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code, encoding

I have a maven project which i am trying to run. But i keep getting this error

```
Execution default of goal nl.geodienstencentrum.maven:sass-maven-plugin:3.7.2:update-stylesheets failed: unknown encoding name - utf8 (nl.geodienstencentrum.maven:sass-maven-plugin:3.7.2:update-stylesheets:default:prepare-package)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal nl.geodienstencentrum.maven:sass-maven-plugin:3.7.2:update-stylesheets failed: unknown encoding name - utf8
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$8(MavenImpl.java:1423)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1422)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$1(MavenBuilder.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$0(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.MainExitException: unknown encoding name - utf8
```

How can i specify the encoding for this plugin? Please suggest any solution.
Thanks

Edit:
I forgot to mention that colleagues can run the project so there seems to be some kind of configuration error on my machine. I am using VSCode with Extension Pack for Java and Spring Boot Extension Pack. I can run the project with eclipse but i would like to use VSCode.

Edit2:
When i modify the pom.xml and put the nl.geodienstencentrum.maven plugins execution in a commenct, the error is gone.

```
<executions>
    <!-- <execution>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>update-stylesheets</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution> -->
</executions>
```

Is there some specific way to set the encoding for the "update-stylesheets" step i am missing?

Comment: The encoding name should be `UTF-8` (or `utf-8`). There were java versions that also allowed `utf8` I believe, but you better find and replace that deviating `utf8`. In style sheets perhaps? Otherwise in a pom.xml.

Comment: I tried to find where that utf8 is coming from but i could only find UTF-8. In the POM Header encoding is set to UTF-8. I think this error is related to the configuration of my local machine/VSCode because i do not get the error within eclipse and my colleagues can run the project too.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, vscode uses UTF-8 encoding by default.You could check the lower right corner and modify it to make sure it is UTF-8.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Encoding of the pom.xml ist set to UTF-8. Do i need so specify the encoding somewhere else too?

Comment: Maven project only needs to modify pom.xml while vscode itself needs to use UTF-8 encoding format. You can following my answer to ensure vscode's format is the same as maven project's.

Comment: Inside the pom.xml aswell as in the bottom right corner menu the encoding is already set to UTF-8. It looks like on your screenshot.